# implementing pipe in C for shell with winapi

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, process, pipe

I m implementing a pipe in C for a shell I am writing, the pipe should be able to support stuff like ls | grep | grep | grep ( in other words, it should be recursive).

Shell is running on cygwin using winapi

I have found two approaches for this:
 using processes or threads.

This is my current pipe function :

```
static void parcmd (void *arg){
    cmddata cdata = *(cmddata*) arg;
    parse_command(cdata.c, cdata.level, cdata.father, cdata.h);
}


static bool do_on_pipe(command_t *cmd1, command_t *cmd2, int level, command_t *father)
{
    bool bRes;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    HANDLE hRead, hWrite;
    DWORD dwRes1, dwRes2;
    handledata hPipeIn, hPipeOut;
    cmddata cmd1_data, cmd2_data;
    HANDLE thread1, thread2;

    ZeroMemory(&sa, sizeof(sa));
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    bRes = CreatePipe(&hRead, &hWrite, &sa, 0);

    //printf("\n\ndo_on_pipe debug write =  %d  read = %d\n", hWrite, hRead);

    hPipeIn.pipeIn = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    hPipeIn.pipeOut = hWrite;

    cmd1_data.c = cmd1;
    cmd1_data.level = level + 1;
    cmd1_data.father = father;
    cmd1_data.h = &hPipeIn;


    thread1 = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, parcmd, &cmd1_data, 0, NULL); 
    //

    hPipeOut.pipeIn = hRead;
    hPipeOut.pipeOut = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    cmd2_data.c = cmd2;
    cmd2_data.level = level + 1;
    cmd2_data.father = father;
    cmd2_data.h = &hPipeOut;



    thread2 = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, parcmd, &cmd2_data, 0, NULL); 
    //

    //DIE(dwRes1 == WAIT_FAILED, "WaitForSingleObject - thd1");

    dwRes1 = WaitForSingleObject(thread1, INFINITE);
    dwRes2 = WaitForSingleObject(thread2, INFINITE);
    //DIE(dwRes2 == WAIT_FAILED, "WaitForSingleObject - thd2");

    CloseHandle(hWrite);
    CloseHandle(hRead); 
    return 0; 
}
```

My issue is that in this current form, the second thread, the one that executes the second command in (cmd1 | cmd2) doesn't stop, basically, I m not getting my prompt back.

if I move  **dwRes1 = WaitForSingleObject(thread1, INFINITE);** before the second thread creation, I am able to succesfully execute a pipe command similar to (cmd1 | cmd2) however, on a cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3, cmd2 prints to stdout whereas cmd3 never stop.

This is the simple command function(it takes input from the parser and executes it) :

```
bool parse_simple(simple_command_t *s, int level, command_t *father, void *h)
{
    /* TODO sanity checks */


        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
        DWORD dwRes;
        BOOL bRes;
        HANDLE inHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        HANDLE outHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        HANDLE errHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
        handledata *hd;


        ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
        ZeroMemory(&sa, sizeof(sa));
        sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;


    if (s->in != NULL) {
        inHandle = getInputHandle(get_word(s->in), sa);
        }


        if (s->out != NULL && s->err != NULL 
            && lstrcmp(get_word(s->out), get_word(s->err)) == 0) {
                outHandle = getOutErrHandle(get_word(s->out), sa, IO_REGULAR);
                errHandle = outHandle;

        } else {
        if (s->out != NULL) {
            if(s->io_flags == IO_OUT_APPEND) {

            outHandle = getOutErrHandle(get_word(s->out), sa, IO_OUT_APPEND);

            } else {

            outHandle = getOutErrHandle(get_word(s->out), sa, IO_REGULAR);

            }
        }
        if(s->err != NULL) {
            if(s->io_flags == IO_ERR_APPEND) {
            errHandle = getOutErrHandle(get_word(s->err), sa, IO_ERR_APPEND);
            } else {
            errHandle = getOutErrHandle(get_word(s->err), sa, IO_REGULAR);
            }
        }
    }
        if(h != NULL) {
        //printf("we got unnull h\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        hd = (handledata *) h;

        if (hd->pipeIn != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            inHandle = hd->pipeIn;
        }

        if(hd->pipeOut != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            outHandle = hd->pipeOut;
        }

        //printf("\n\nhandle debug cmd = %s write =  %d  read = %d\n",get_argv(s), hd->pipeOut, hd->pipeIn);
        fflush(stdout);

        }



        RedirectAllHandles(&si, inHandle, outHandle, errHandle);
        //printf("\n\nhandles after redirect for cmd = %s write =  %d  read = %d err = %d\n",get_argv(s), outHandle, inHandle, errHandle);
        fflush(stdout);

        if (lstrcmp(get_word(s->verb), "exit") == 0 || 
            lstrcmp(get_word(s->verb), "quit") == 0 ||
            lstrcmp(get_word(s->verb), "cd") == 0)
        {
            //internal command
            if (lstrcmp(get_word(s->verb), "exit") == 0 || 
            lstrcmp(get_word(s->verb), "quit") == 0) {
                shell_exit();
            } else if (lstrcmp(get_word(s->verb), "cd") == 0) {
            return shell_cd(s->params);
            }

        } else 
        if (strchr(get_word(s->verb), '=') != NULL) {
         // env val
        } else {

        bRes =  CreateProcess( 
        NULL,           /* No module name (use command line) */
        get_argv(s),        /* Command line */
        NULL,           /* Process handle not inheritable */
        NULL,           /* Thread handle not inheritable */
        TRUE,          /* Set handle inheritance to FALSE */
        0,              /* No creation flags */
        NULL,           /* Use parent's environment block */
        NULL,           /* Use parent's starting directory */ 
        &si,            /* Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure */
        &pi             /* Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure */
    ); 

    if (!bRes)
    {
        printf("Execution failed for '%s'\n", get_argv(s));
        return false;
    }
    //printf("cmd %s waiting for process\n", get_argv(s));
    dwRes = WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    //todo add die
    //printf("cmd %s process done\n", get_argv(s));
    bRes = GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &dwRes);
    //todo add die
    //printf("cmd %s got to handles\n", get_argv(s));
    CloseHandle(inHandle);
    CloseHandle(outHandle);
    CloseHandle(errHandle);
    //printf("cmd %s got to closed handles\n", get_argv(s));

    return dwRes;

    }

    return 0; /* TODO replace with actual exit status */
}
```

And the function that decides what function to call based on cases:

```
int parse_command(command_t *c, int level, command_t *father, void *h)
{
    /* TODO sanity checks */
    int status;
    if (c->op == OP_NONE) {
        /* TODO execute a simple command */
        return parse_simple(c->scmd, level, c, h);
        return 0; /* TODO replace with actual exit code of command */
    }

    switch (c->op) {
    case OP_SEQUENTIAL:
        /* TODO execute the commands one after the other */
            parse_command(c->cmd1, level + 1, c, h);
            return parse_command(c->cmd2, level + 1, c, h);
        break;

    case OP_PARALLEL:
        /* TODO execute the commands simultaneously */
        return do_in_parallel(c->cmd1, c->cmd2, level + 1, c);
        break;

    case OP_CONDITIONAL_NZERO:
        /* TODO execute the second command only if the first one
         * returns non zero */
        status = parse_command(c->cmd1, level + 1, c, h);
        if (!status)
            return status;
        return parse_command(c->cmd2, level + 1, c, h);

        break;

    case OP_CONDITIONAL_ZERO:
        status = parse_command(c->cmd1, level + 1, c, h);
        if (status)
            return status;
        return parse_command(c->cmd2, level + 1, c, h);
        /* TODO execute the second command only if the first one
         * returns zero */
        break;

    case OP_PIPE:
            do_on_pipe(c->cmd1, c->cmd2,level, c);
        /* TODO redirect the output of the first command to the
         * input of the second */
        break;

    default:
        return SHELL_EXIT;
    }

    return 0; /* TODO replace with actual exit code of command */
}
```

I know it's a large code base and it's unlikely to get any response, but I have been working on this issue for two to three days in a row and I simply cannot see the solution, how can I achieve a functional piping like ( cmd1 | cmd2 ... | cmdN) with this code ? Thank you!

Comment: You say that when you run "cmd1 | cmd2" you need to wait for cmd1 before running cmd2.  This won't work.  What happens if cmd1 produces gigabytes of output?  Where will it go?  You need to launch cmd1 with its output connected to a new pipe and then immediately launch cmd2 with its input connected to the same pipe.  I'd suggest you get this working with external commands before tackling internal commands, though it's much the same.  Also note that |, ||, & and && are really binary operators.  In cmd.exe, `(dir & dir) | grep` is not the same as `dir & dir | grep`, which is `dir & (dir | grep)`.

Comment: I reedited the whole post with my new version of what I have achieved, I am far more concerned with getting normal piping to work than the binary operators you mentioned(and which you are probably right about)

Answer (score 0):

Create a function

```
Execute(c, stdin, stdout, stderr, wait)
```

If wait is true this executes c and waits for it to finish otherwise it executes c and returns a handle that can be waited on for completion

In pseudo-code, the implementation is something like:

```
if c is an external command:
    launch process
    if (wait)
        wait for it to complete
    else
        return process handle

In all other cases:

if (!wait) create thread and return thread handle

Then, on the new thread (if created) or the existing thread:

if c is an internal command:
    Call the internal code for the command

if c is `a | b`:
    Create pipe
    waita = Execute(a, stdin, pipein, stderr, false)
    Execute(b, pipeout, stdout, stderr, true)
    Wait on waita

if c is `a & b`:
    Execute(a, stdin, stdout, stderr, true)
    Execute(b, stdin, stdout, stderr, true)
```

Note that with this design you need to finish the parsing before attempting to execute anything.